# Подскажите, как сделать такие бордеры?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Подскажите, как сделать такие бордеры?
Все эти пункты представляют из себя дивы, которым задан float left.

[image: <code>введите сюда описание изображения</code>]

Answer (score 6):

Например еще так:

```css
.item+.item {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.row+.row{
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}


/* Доп. стилизация для наглядности */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  width: 33.3333%;
  height: 200px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если число колонок заранее неизвестно, можно рисовать границы у всех, но при этом скрывать границы слева и сверху с `overflow:hidden`. Хотя, подозреваю, это не очень-то корректно.

https://jsfiddle.net/7kputd11/

```css
.blocks {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blocks-wrapper {
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
}

.block {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-top: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="blocks-wrapper">
    <div class="block">A</div>
    <div class="block">B</div>
    <div class="block">C</div>
    <div class="block">D</div>
    <div class="block">E</div>
    <div class="block">F</div>
    <div class="block">G</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нет, результат совсем не тот выходит...

Answer (score 1):

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 120px;
}

.block:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}

.row:first-child .block {
  border-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="block">A</div>
  <div class="block">B</div>
  <div class="block">C</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="block">D</div>
  <div class="block">E</div>
  <div class="block">F</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.block {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  }
.clear {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  }
.borderRightBot {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  }
.borderBot {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  }
.borderRight {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  }
```

```html
<div class="block borderRightBot"></div>
<div class="block borderRightBot"></div>
<div class="block borderBot"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="block borderRight"></div>
<div class="block borderRight"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: да, но здесь каждому блоку задан свой класс. А если сайт будет просматриваться на более маленьком экране и расположение блоков будет другим? Будет странно смотреться...

Comment: Для более маленьких устройств устанавливается более маленькая ширина блоков реализовать можно через медиа запросы.